# Word has moved my document text *inside* a field code. How do I get it back?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

OK. Random question, somehow, word has managed to move the entire contents of my document (7500 odd words including assorted field codes for a citation manager) into a field code that stretches over the entire document. The first page looks like this.

[image]

If I convert the field to text, it wipes everything, because the code doesn't actually do anything as far as word is concerned. I can't reliably select the contents of the field because the document is too big.

Is there a way of turning it back into normal text? Preferably with the embedded field codes intact?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This likely happened when you had everything selected and pressed Ctrl+F9 instead of F9.*

### Option 1

You could put an extra space at the beginning and end of the errant field and then copy everything between those two spaces to a new document. Then delete the errant field and copy/paste the content back.

### Option 2

You could run it through Word MVP Graham Mayor's [Field Code to Text converter](http://www.gmayor.com/export_field.htm) and back. That page also has the macros shown below. *(I recommend using the Add-In.)* Remove the outside field brackets before converting back. You may have to do the converting back field by field. *Do this with a copy of your document because you will have to restore formatting.*

### Option 3

You could make the field into a working field. Put an `QUOTE "` at the beginning of the field and another quotation mark `"` at the end.

```
Sub FieldCodeToString()
Dim oRng as Range
Dim Fieldstring As String
Dim NewString As String
Dim CurrChar As String
Dim CurrSetting As Boolean
Dim fcDisplay As Object
Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim X As  Long
NewString = ""
Set fcDisplay = ActiveWindow.View
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
CurrSetting = fcDisplay.ShowFieldCodes
If CurrSetting <> True Then fcDisplay.ShowFieldCodes = True
Set oRng = Selection.Range
Fieldstring = oRng.Text
For X = 1 To Len(Fieldstring)
CurrChar = Mid(Fieldstring, X, 1)
Select Case CurrChar
Case Chr(19)
CurrChar = "{"
Case Chr(21)
CurrChar = "}"
Case Else
End Select
NewString = NewString + CurrChar
Next X
oRng.Text = NewString
Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.SetText NewString
MyData.PutInClipboard
fcDisplay.ShowFieldCodes = CurrSetting
End Sub
```

And, to reverse the process:

```
Sub FieldStringToCode()
' Based on a macro provided by Paul Edstein
' Converts "textual" field codes into real field codes
' To do the conversion, simply paste the "textual" field codes
' into your document, select them and run the macro.
Dim RngFld As Range
Dim RngTmp As Range
Dim oFld As Field
Dim StrTmp As String
Dim sUpdate As String
Dim bFldCodes As Boolean
Const Msg1 = "Select the text to convert and try again."
Const Msg2 = "There are no field strings in the selected range."
Const Msg3 = "Unmatched field brace pairs in the selected range."
Const Title1 = "Error!"
Const Title2 = "Update fields?"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
bFldCodes = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes
If Selection.Type <> wdSelectionNormal Then
MsgBox Msg1, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, Title1
Exit Sub
End If
If InStr(1, Selection.Text, "{") = 0 Or InStr(1, Selection.Text, "}") = 0 Then
MsgBox Msg2, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, Title1
End If
If Len(Replace(Selection.Text, "{", vbNullString)) <> Len(Replace(Selection.Text, "}", vbNullString)) Then
MsgBox Msg3, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, Title1
Exit Sub
End If
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
Set RngFld = Selection.Range
With RngFld
.End = .End + 1
Do While InStr(1, .Text, "{") > 0
Set RngTmp = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=.Start + InStr(.Text, "{") - 1, End:=.Start + InStr(.Text, "}"))
With RngTmp
Do While Len(Replace(.Text, "{", vbNullString)) <> Len(Replace(.Text, "}", vbNullString))
.End = .End + 1
If .Characters.Last.Text <> "}" Then .MoveEndUntil cset:="}", Count:=Len(ActiveDocument.Range(.End, RngFld.End))
Loop
.Characters.First = vbNullString
.Characters.Last = vbNullString
StrTmp = .Text
Set oFld = ActiveDocument.Fields.Add(Range:=RngTmp, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="", PreserveFormatting:=False)
oFld.Code.Text = StrTmp
End With
Loop
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = bFldCodes
.End = .End - 1
If bFldCodes = False Then .Fields.ToggleShowCodes
.Select
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
sUpdate = MsgBox("Do you wish to update the fields?" & vbCr + vbCr & _
"Note that if the converted fields include ASK or FILLIN fields, " & _
"updating will force the prompt for input to those fields", vbYesNo, Title2)
If sUpdate = vbYes Then RngFld.Fields.Update
Set RngTmp = Nothing
Set RngFld = Nothing
Set oFld = Nothing
End Sub
```